# Using weights in R for ChiSquare and Spearmen where weights are different for gender categories

Tags: dataframe, data-manipulation, survey, chi-squared, weighted

Quite new hear, but longtime reader, so please excuse any first time problems
At the moment I am working on a dataset, where I want to not only show the relations in the data via cross tables, but also using correlational methods such as chi-square and spearmen.

This is the table I am currently struggling with (rows are gender, columns are degrees of agreement form survey participants to a statement).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2of5.png)

I now looked at the distribution of gender I looked at and now have a weight value (shortened for better reading):
For 1 (male) it is 1.1
For 2 (female) it is 0.9

And on the next step, I am stuck. I found solutions, where I could apply weights, which however wouldn't allow a selection of what weight goes to what item. Another solution I found was applying weights not via the chi-sqaure function, but on the data set, however I could not work out the concrete steps to make it work via that solution.

I also lastly tried to just make a table and change the values of the table by hand and to then feed the table to the chi-squared function. This does work, but is a quite work intensive solution for the whole survey :/

I would be really thankful if somebody could show me the way, as this is one of the last steps missing to be able to finish my work! :)